# SQL TRY Error not CATCHING

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

Have a stored procedure and have wrapped the code in the format

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        ...code
    COMMIT
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    ...code
END CATCH
```

Which works fine until I started doing some testing for various errors to make sure they were being entered into my log table correctly.

However, when I run this, it fails, and does not rollback and requires a manual rollback.  It's like the code does not realise that it is in a TRY block.

Any ideas? (Code below, hoping it can be recreated on someone else's system and not some bizarre way on how the systems where I am are configured)

```
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRAN

            --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            -- Create test table
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateOfBirth') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateOfBirth
            CREATE TABLE #DateOfBirth
            (
                DateOfBirth DATE
            )
            INSERT INTO #DateOfBirth
            VALUES
                ('1984-12-09')
                ,('1977-12-09')
                ,('2015-03-12')
                ,('1967-01-15')

            --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
            -- Date Of Birth
                -- This Insert errors
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DOB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DOB
            CREATE TABLE #DOB
            (
                groupID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                , DateOfBirth INT -- Data Type mismatch
            )

            INSERT INTO #DOB
            SELECT DateOfBirth
            FROM #DateOfBirth

        COMMIT
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT 'Rollback'

        ROLLBACK

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage   NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorState     INT = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrorSeverity  INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    END CATCH

END
GO
```

Comment: You say it fails, but giev no details? Is it simply not doingas you expect? A `CATCH` won't be entered if something doesn't do as you expect, as error has to occur. If an there is an error, why haven't you posted it? :)

Comment: The error was in the code, it says Data Type mismatch.  Basically, I was trying to catch various errors to log into a table and was not expecting there to be an error that didn't pass through to the catch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation errors within the same scope of the CATCH block cannot be caught. To wit, add a PRINT before each statement:

```
PRINT 'BATCH STARTED';
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

        PRINT 'BEGIN TRAN';
        BEGIN TRAN;

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateOfBirth') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateOfBirth;

        PRINT 'CREATING #DateOfBirth';
        CREATE TABLE #DateOfBirth
        (
            DateOfBirth DATE
        );

        PRINT 'INSERTING INTO #DateOfBirth';
        INSERT INTO #DateOfBirth
        VALUES
            ('1984-12-09')
            ,('1977-12-09')
            ,('2015-03-12')
            ,('1967-01-15')

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DOB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DOB;

        PRINT 'CREATING #DOB';
        CREATE TABLE #DOB
        (
            groupID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
            , DateOfBirth INT -- Data Type mismatch
        );

        PRINT 'INSERTING INTO #DOB';
        INSERT INTO #DOB
        SELECT DateOfBirth
        FROM #DateOfBirth;

        PRINT 'COMMIT';
        COMMIT;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT 'ROLLBACK';

        ROLLBACK;

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage   NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorState     INT = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrorSeverity  INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    END CATCH;

END;
GO
```

When this batch is initially executed on a new session, the resultant messages are:

```
BATCH STARTED
BEGIN TRAN
CREATING #DateOfBirth
INSERTING INTO #DateOfBirth
CREATING #DOB
INSERTING INTO #DOB
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 36
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

The important point is that this error occurs during statement compilation, not execution. Because the temp tables do not exist when the batch is compiled, compilation of the statements referencing those tables is deferred until the statements are run. Any errors that occur during the compilation can't be caught in by the CATCH block in the same scope.

The compilation error can be caught if you execute the statements using dynamic SQL so that the compilation occurs in a different scope:

```
PRINT 'BATCH STARTED';
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY

        PRINT 'BEGIN TRAN';
        BEGIN TRAN;

        EXECUTE('
        IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#DateOfBirth'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateOfBirth;

        PRINT ''CREATING #DateOfBirth'';
        CREATE TABLE #DateOfBirth
        (
            DateOfBirth DATE
        );

        PRINT ''INSERTING INTO #DateOfBirth'';
        INSERT INTO #DateOfBirth
        VALUES
            (''1984-12-09'')
            ,(''1977-12-09'')
            ,(''2015-03-12'')
            ,(''1967-01-15'')

        IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#DOB'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DOB;

        PRINT ''CREATING #DOB'';
        CREATE TABLE #DOB
        (
            groupID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
            , DateOfBirth INT -- Data Type mismatch
        );

        PRINT ''INSERTING INTO #DOB'';
        INSERT INTO #DOB
        SELECT DateOfBirth
        FROM #DateOfBirth;

        PRINT ''COMMIT'';
        COMMIT;
        ');


    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        PRINT 'ROLLBACK';

        ROLLBACK;

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage   NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                @ErrorState     INT = ERROR_STATE(),
                @ErrorSeverity  INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    END CATCH;

END;
GO
```

In this case, the CATCH block is entered and the transaction rolled back:

```
BATCH STARTED
BEGIN TRAN
CREATING #DateOfBirth
INSERTING INTO #DateOfBirth
CREATING #DOB
INSERTING INTO #DOB
ROLLBACK
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 2, Line 58
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

BTW, I strongly recommend you specify 'SET XACT_ABORT ON' to help ensure the transaction is rolled back after errors in cases where the CATCH block is not executed (e.g. a client query timeout error).

Comment: Nope, if I run that script in a new window then it prints.  If I run without the print first, then run with the print then it doesn't print.  Assuming because of some caching facilities or something

Comment: Thanks Dan, appreciate the explanation.  That clarifies everything I was confused about.  Appreciate it.  Sidenote:  Never used `SET XACT` so before I wrote this comment I looked it up and someone linked to a blog by a person with the same name as you ;p.  So double thanks haha.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're having is this:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 39
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

For this type of error, it is suggested to handle in the application scope, since the batch is simply aborted.

I've compiled a few resources:

- [Book](https://books.google.pt/books?id=13ayznPwlysC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=Operand%20type%20clash%20transaction&source=bl&ots=OhGW3kUqHc&sig=S4-NRJhuk9h0t7JWMbNCzWiTt0A&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidyZf9ibrZAhXExRQKHQPtBgsQ6AEIYTAE#v=onepage&q=Operand%20type%20clash%20transaction&f=false)
- [Post on SQLSunday.com](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/04/13/error-handling-using-try-catch/)
- [Post from Brent Ozar & Team](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/try-catch-doesnt-handle/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is a compile time error, not a runtime error. It's suggested to handle by fixing the problem, not at runtime.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree with you, but as a last resort, you can handle it in the application.

Comment: No, you can't. The only thing you can do with this in the application level is to log the exception and show the user a "friendly" message, however such errors should not find their way into production code in the first place.

Comment: It's not exactly a compile error, since it runs. https://imgur.com/a/MpZkO

It's a strange behaviour.

Comment: No, it doesn't run. Try add `CREATE PROCEDURE testZZZZZ AS` before the code and see for yourself that the procedure is not created.

Comment: I was able to do it. Here it is. https://imgur.com/a/yiFFa I've created a stored procedure and run it.

Comment: Really? What version of SQL Server? mine is 2016 and refused to create the procedure.

Comment: Yes. SQL Server Enterprise 2016 (13.0.4001.0). Well, it's a strange problem, It should not happen. Although, I agree with you. It should be fixed in development. Cheers

Comment: Well, I'm glad I'm not the only one that felt it was a bit odd. @ZoharPeled -  This pattern was in a stored procedure.  Yeah, it wouldn't be in production, was trying to test my logging facilities and forcing various errors in the stored procedure and when I done that, it just sort of ended and doesn't log.  (Where I am currently working, an error that shouldn't exist seems to be the norm because of all the chefs to the broth so testing every possibility).   Thanks for the info all, appreciated.  (Not quite sure what the answer is other than not to let it happen, will accept an answer later)